# Where does Laverna stored my local notes?

Tags: laverna

I have downloaded Laverna, disabled any clouds and got the following directory

[image]

I ran `laverna` was able to create a note and it persists after application closed then reopened.

Where did it stored this note?

Comment: Have you checked your home directory?

Comment: I have a lot of files there. Where are Laverna's?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, check in ~/.config/laverna.